# Since today, I cannot access netscape.javascript.* classes within Eclipse

Tags: java, applet, netscape

Since today, my Eclipse fails to load `JSObject`.  This code was previously working OK. Any ideas how to fix it?  I do have simple `netscape.jar` in the classpath.

Here is the code that now fails to work:

```
import netscape.javascript.*;

  ...

    try {
        doc = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(app); //.getMember("document");
    } catch(JSException e) {
        doc = null;
        Debug.error("DBscorm().<init>: Exception " + e);
        throw(e);
    } catch(Exception e){
        doc = null;
        Debug.error("DBscorm().<init>: Exception " + e);
        throw(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every JDK subfolder is a file called plugin.jar

Get this file and add it to your Eclipse classpath. This will make it work - guaranteed.

Comment: does Appletviewer support it?

Comment: Not every JDK has plugin.jar. For older ones you have to use jaws.jar (e.g. jdk1.2.2\jre\lib\jaws.jar )

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

- Do you have a missing import statement? Try organising imports with CTRL+SHIFT+O
- Is the netscape.jar still configured as a library for the project? (Project Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries tab, then click on "Add JARs..." if necessary)