# Error: java: package netscape.javascript does not exist

Tags: java

I was trying to run [JHotDraw](https://sourceforge.net/p/jhotdraw/wiki/Home/) 7.0.6
but I got this error. How can I solve this?

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'JHotDraw 7.0.6'
Information:javac 1.8.0_242 was used to compile java sources
Information:2/19/20, 11:36 AM - Compilation completed with 14 errors and 10 warnings in 4s 986ms
/project/path/JHotDraw 7.0.6/src/org/jhotdraw/samples/draw/DrawLiveConnectApplet.java
Error:(31, 1) java: package netscape.javascript does not exist
Error:(125, 21) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class JSObject
Error:(125, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: variable JSObject
Error:(251, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSObject
  location: class org.jhotdraw.samples.draw.DrawLiveConnectApplet
Error:(251, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable JSObject
  location: class org.jhotdraw.samples.draw.DrawLiveConnectApplet
```

I looked into this https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/package-netscape-javascript-does-not-exist.140950/
and this [Since today, I cannot access netscape.javascript.* classes within Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751428/since-today-i-cannot-access-netscape-javascript-classes-within-eclipse) but they did not help me much!

Comment: Travel back in time to when Applets were supported. About [four years ago](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/80-java/9391-oracle-annouces-the-end-of-java-applet-support.html) Oracle announced support was ending, but it was pretty much moot then anyway (because the browsers had started blocking it). So I would guess you want a browser that's about ten years old. So time machine.

Comment: I am not quite getting what you are saying but I am trying to run the program in IntelliJ not in a browser. Can you elaborate more, in a simpler way, on what you were saying? please!

Comment: *I am trying to run the program in IntelliJ not in a browser* `netscape.javascript` [Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape) ***was*** a browser (a very ***early*** browser). That package was for Applet / Browser integration, and was adopted (because it was first) by **all** browsers (well, I guess the Applet plug-in was). Regardless, it's a distinction that hardly matters now, Applets are **dead**.

Comment: See also [Invoking JavaScript Code From an Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) and the [`netscape.JSObject` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/jdk.jsobject/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html).